# Tomcat 8 installation

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I am installing tomcat 8 to unbuntu 14.04 and have been following this tutorial:

[How to install Apache Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I'm at the stage of installing an upstart script in `/etc/init/tomcat.conf`. The problem is that i am trying to replicate the setup of our other server (set up before i started working here by someone who no longer works for the company). In the tutorial it says to use `/opt/tomcat` as `CATALINA_HOME` however the setup for the current server has `CATALINA_HOME` as `/var/lib/tomcat8`. My questions are as follows:

- Why would there be this discrepancy?
- Is setting `CATALINA_HOME` to `/var/lib/tomcat8` as simple as changing the env CATALINA_HOME from `/opt/tomcat` to `/var/lib/tomcat8`?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, you can set `CATALINA_HOME` to `/var/lib/tomcat8`.

The `/opt/` Path looks to me like the tomcat in the old setup was installed manually not using any packagemanager.